# Rails 3/4: How to increment and save database value by link_to

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, database

I have a database with users, vendors, and accounts.

user has an account, account has an integer value credits

vendor has an integer value, product count

I want to be able to have a button on my app that when a button is clicked it will update these two items in the database:

```
 current_user.account.credits
 vendor.product_count
```

I am still vert new to rails and don't really know how it all works yet, so would love some help :D

My git repo on bit bucket so you can examine the code:
https://umlungu@bitbucket.org/umlungu/mybeans.git

Answer (score 0):

On the button_to, you supply parameters that get passed into the controller, and the controller operates based on the received parameters. So far you've not given any information about what controller, what view, or whatever, so the answer is likewise general in nature.

In the view:

```
<%= button_to 'Something', {controller: "some_controller", action: "some_action", credits: credits, vendor_id: vendor.id} %>
```

In the controller "some_controller"

```
  def some_action
    credits = params[:credits]
    credits ||= 0
    vendor_id = params[:vendor_id]

    # find the current user, and update its credits
    # find the vendor and update the product count?
    # send your user somewhere
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi rails dog. 
Thanks for your reply. I will share a link to my git repo so you can have a look. Please excuse the terrible coding structure. I am making it up as I go along :p

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/umlungu/mybeans.git
Theres the git repo, so you can have a look at the controllers etc.

Comment: What I want to do, is on the view for vendor show.
views/vendors/show.html
I want to have 3 buttons.
Each button will.
decrement current_user.account.credits by 1 and the second action will be decrement vendor.product_count by 1

Comment: I tried doing what you said using these
<%= button_to 'Buy Expresso', {controller: "vendors_controller",    action: "expresso_stock_dec", expresso_count: @vendor.expresso_count, id: @vendor.id} %>

and this:
       def expresso_stock_dec
        expresso_count = params[:expresso_count]
        expresso_count ||= 0
        expresso_count -1
      end

And it now throws a no routes error

Comment: You are trying to use a "vendor" route, "expresso_stock_dec", that you have not declared in your routes.rb. Hence to no routes error, because you haven't told rails that you want one.

Comment: Would this be the correct route?
put "expresso_stock_dec" => "vendors#expresso_stock_dec"